# Can the [cmdlet] tag and the [cmdlets] tag be made synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have the [cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlet) tag and the [cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlets) tag. Here is the description for the [cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlet) tag:

> A cmdlet is a lightweight Windows PowerShell script that performs a single function.

And for [cmdlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmdlets)

> Cmdlets are lightweight, task-oriented commands in the Windows PowerShell environment. Cmdlets can be connected together in a pipeline to share input/output

Given that they refer to the same thing, can they be made synonyms? I don't really see a good reason to have them be seperate tags.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm also seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pscmdlet and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-cmdlet -- the second one here seems like the better synonym target, and I have no idea if the first one is related to this or not. I'm not an SME

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I agree, making all of them the same is right. Thanks!